# I want to update every line at once. Use the angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs

Using angularjs made ​​the list function.
Try to make the update function.
I do not know how to create the updateReq.
I will use a variables that is in the loop 
I do not know how to put variables on the updateReq.
thank you

`enter code here`

start();

```
function start() {



    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){


        $scope.init = function() {

            console.log("${pageContext.request.contextPath}");
            console.log('${pageContext.request.serverName}');
        }

        $scope.productsList = function(){

            var selectsiteCode = $('#search_form').find("#scode").text();

            if(selectsiteCode != null && selectsiteCode!= "" && selectsiteCode!="undefined")
            {
            $http({
                method : 'get',
                url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products/productsList?selectsiteCode=' + selectsiteCode,
                param : {

                } 

                })
                .success(function($data){
                    $scope.selectResult = $data;
                    $scope.ProductsList = $data;
                });
            }
            else
                {
                    alert("choses store");
                }
        }


        $scope.productsUpdate = function() {

            var updateReq = new Object();

            updateReq.siteCode = $("siteCode_{{$index}}").val;
            alert(updateReq.siteCode);
        }



    }]);

    } ]);
}
```

```
             `enter code here`<form>
                <div align = "right">
                    <button ng-click="productsUpdate()" >save</button>
                </div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="Tuser" >
                        <thead style="text-align:center">
                            <tr>

                                <td>sitecode</td>
                                <td>productscode</td>
                                <td>productsname</td>
                                <td>price</td>
                                <td>kitchenPRT</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id = "select_check" style="text-align:center">
                            <tr ng-model='selectproducts' ng-repeat = "item in selectResult | orderBy : 'itemID'">
                                <td><input type="text" id='siteCode_{{$index}}'  value= "{{item.siteCode}}" disabled kr-Input></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id='itemID_{{$index}}' value = "{{item.itemID}}" disabled kr-Input></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id='itemName_{{$index}}' value = "{{item.itemName}}"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id='itemAmt_{{$index}}' value = "{{item.itemAmt}}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="kitchenPRT_Y_{{$index}}" class = 'form-control' >
                                        <option id="kitchenPRT_Y_{{$index}}" value='{{ item.kitchenPRT_Y =="Y" ? "Y" : "N" }}'>{{ item.kitchenPRT_Y =="Y" ? "Y" : "N" }}</option>
                                        <option id="kitchenPRT_Y_{{$index}}" value='{{ item.kitchenPRT_Y !="Y" ? "Y" : "N" }}'>{{ item.kitchenPRT_Y !="Y" ? "Y" : "N" }}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the product object in the `$scope` in your controller :

```
$scope.product = {};
```

> **Scope :**  is an object that refers to the application model. It is an execution context for expressions.

You have to use `ng-model` (**Data Binding**) in your input to track new attrribute values :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.name">
```

> **Data Binding :**   is the automatic synchronization of data between the model and view components. The way that Angular implements
>   data-binding lets you treat the model as the single-source-of-truth in
>   your application.

[image]

Now you can simply add the update request that is binded to your submit button :

```
<button ng-click="productsUpdate()" >save</button>
```

Update request using Http **PUT** method (retrieve the new product from `$scope`) :

```
$scope.productsUpdate = function() {
 var req = {
   method: 'PUT',
   url: 'http://example.com',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': undefined
   },
   //Get the new product
   data: $scope.product;
  }
  $http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
}
```

Comment: Mine anxious, it is intended to be transmitted by putting the value of each column of the index updateReq object. I think I want to know the '$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});' sorry

Comment: Can't understand your need.

Comment: There are variables column.
I try to update all the rows based on the 'itemID_{{$index}}' variables. The updateReq object can put one row at a time. I want to update all rows at a time